# AWS lambda how to create multipart response in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I migrated an existing .NET Core service to AWS Lambda and I am not sure how to send the correct multipart response from my `function.cs`.

The original .NET Core service returned an `IActionResult` and produced a multipart response, consisting of a an XML for the first part, and a 64-bit encoded html string for the 2nd part.

I tried various return types including `IActionResult` and none of them produce the same multi-part output the original REST service did. Using the code below, my response is:

```
{}
```

How do I return the following structure from the function.cs?

Multipart response

```
--d3742228-85fc-4218-bf24-7e9dec746710
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-id: ACORD

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ACORD>
  <InsuranceSvcRs>
    <Status>
      <StatusCd>0</StatusCd>
      <StatusDesc>Success</StatusDesc>
    </Status>
  </InsuranceSvcRs>
</ACORD>
--d3742228-85fc-4218-bf24-7e9dec746710
Content-Type: application/html; charset=utf-8
Content-id: Inquiry.html
Content-description: Response to View Inquiry

PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICctLy9XM0MvL0RURC=
--d3742228-85fc-4218-bf24-7e9dec746710--
```

Code snippet from `function.cs`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FunctionHandler(ApiGatewayRequest.Root input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    IActionResult? ugResult = null;
    var result = controller.Post(apiGatewayRequest.body); //return multip-part response
    ugResult = result.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
    return ugResult;
}
```

Partial code inside original rest controller function named `Post`:

```
[HttpPost, Route("/api/Post")]
[Consumes("application/xml", "text/xml", "text/plain", "application/octet-stream", "application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string xmlfile)
{
    acordXml = await _gateway.ProcessIncomingRequestAndReturnXMLString(modifiedRequest, logTimeStamp);
    string htmlResponse = _gateway.CreateHtmlString(modifiedRequest, logTimeStamp);
    return new XmlAndEncodedHtmlMultipartResult().SetEncodedHtmlContent(htmlResponse).SetXmlContent(acordXml);
}
```

`XmlAndEncodedHtmlMultipartResult` class  used to create multipart response in Rest:

```
public class XmlAndEncodedHtmlMultipartResult : IActionResult
{
    private StringContent _xmlContent;
    private StringContent _htmlContent;
    public static string Subtype = "related";//my-xml+html
    private MultipartContent _multipartContent = new MultipartContent(Subtype); 

    public XmlAndEncodedHtmlMultipartResult SetXmlContent(string xml, string contentId = "ACORD")
    {
        var xmlContent = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        xmlContent.Headers.Add("Content-id", contentId);
        this._xmlContent = xmlContent;
        return this;
    }

    public XmlAndEncodedHtmlMultipartResult SetEncodedHtmlContent(string rawHtml, string contentId = "Inquiry.html", string description = "Response to View Inquiry")
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawHtml);
        var encodedHtml = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        var htmlContent = new StringContent(encodedHtml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/html");
        htmlContent.Headers.Add("Content-id", contentId);
        htmlContent.Headers.Add("Content-description", description);
        this._htmlContent = htmlContent;
        return this;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        this._multipartContent.Add(this._xmlContent);

        if(this._htmlContent != null)
            this._multipartContent.Add(this._htmlContent);

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = this._multipartContent.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
        await _multipartContent.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a stand-alone Lambda function that serves as a wrapper around the controller endpoint of interest -- you may have better luck instantiating/running your entire NET Core Web API project within a single Lambda function using the AWS provided NuGet package `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer` and calling your existing endpoint of interest and examining the response.

Updating an existing ASP.NET Core project to run in Lambda fronted by API Gateway is a very painless process and you should have greater parity with your application's HTTP responses instead of trying to mimic the server response with your Lambda function handler.

References:
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer/README.md

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/running-serverless-asp-net-core-web-apis-with-amazon-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this technique call to an existing API? I ask because the AWS version of this service is replacing the on-premises version. There will be no existing API to call from this approach.

Comment: No problem!  Basically this suggested approach would be to run your entire Web API application, the one that includes the endpoint of interest with the multi-part response, inside of a single Lambda function.  This approach would encapsulate the running of the entire WebAPI project within a single Lambda function --  the Proxy Integration feature of API Gateway will capture the request, spin up the entire app in a Lambda function, pass the request for processing to your app, and then return the response back to API Gateway and to the requester.

Comment: So instead of declaring a Lambda function/handler that is essentially just a wrapper that 
 invokes the method/controller of interest programmatically (e.g. your explicit call to controller.Post(apiGatewayRequest.body)) - this approach would have the actual app with that controller/endpoint running -- and have the request go through the entire request processing pipeline of your Web API project [since the entire API project would be running as normal], hit your controller, hit specific method endpoint and be processed and return back out through the request processing pipeline.

Comment: I will give this a try and provide feedback. Thanks for the help.

Comment: is there a simple example of this somewhere?

Comment: This article targets the new minimal API feature of newer versions of .NET but the steps are the same for the classic controller based endpoints: https://clearmeasure.com/hosting-dot-net-6-minimal-api-aws-lambda/

Comment: This is a great video on this topic as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rImaNyfKhZk&ab_channel=NickChapsas